# JAVA/Swing (Eclipse) : Program works step by step but not in normal execution

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have a job to do for school. There is a window where there are pigeons, and by clicking the mouse we place some food that pigeons have to eat. To make it simple, I use swing to paint some filled round for food and filled square for pigeons. Pigeons and Foods are Threads that have a PigeonShape or FoodShape object that are JPanels.

When I place my food, pigeons move in the right direction. The problem is that, because I use swing, I have to repaint the PigeonShape each time I change its positions. Here is the code in Pigeon.java :

The `run()` :

```
public void run(){
    while(true){
        try {
            sleep(25);
            this.observe(); //just to check what is the closest piece of Food, we don't care here
            this.move();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `move()` :

```
private void move(){
    //If there is available food, the Pigeon has to move to it
    if(this.closest != null){

        /* 
         * some calculations for the move 
         * coordonates are stored in xPigeon et yPigeon that are integers
         */

        //it makes the PigeonShape disappear because the background is white too
        this.draw.setColor(Color.WHITE); //(1)
        this.draw.repaint(); //(2)

        //it changes coordinates of the Pigeon
        //each time those functions are called, it call the same function for this.draw (the PigeonShape)
        this.setPosX(xPigeon);
        this.setPosY(yPigeon);

        //it makes the PigeonShape reappear
        this.draw.setColor(CURIOUS); //(3)
        this.draw.repaint(); //(4)
    } 
}
```

(In the above code, `this.draw` is the object PigeonShape that represents this Pigeon, and `CURIOUS`is a private static Color equal to Color.GREEN)

The problem is that in normal execution, the PigeonShape moves, lines (3) et (4) are done but not (1) and (2). In the window, it keeps previous positions the Pigeon had : [image]

(when the PigeonShape is green, it meens that it is curious, and when it is blue, it is asleep)

But when I debug step by step, lines (1) and (2) are correctly done and I don't have the trail of the move !

I don't understand why it works when debugging step by step but not in normal execution... Could you help me please ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it keeps previous positions the Pigeon had :

You need to invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` as the first statement when you override the `paintComponent(...)` method. This will clear the background before doing the custom painting.

Comment: I am not sure if I have understand. Do you mean that `super.paintComponent()` must be called in the JPanel's `paintComponent()` before doing anything ? Like this :
`public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(this.color);
  g.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, 60, 60);
 }`
?

Comment: I tried it, it does not keep the trail anymore but now my pieces of food doesn't appear....

Comment: @Nicaps, `Do you mean...` Yes, that is correct. `now my pieces of food doesn't appear` Well you need to paint your food pieces in the paintComponent() method along with all your other painting. That is every time the paintComponent() method is called you need to paint all the objects you want to see.

Comment: It's a bit heavy, if each Pigeon must repaint all others object, no ? Moreover, if I have two or more Pigeons, it makes them blinking while they paint each other.

Comment: Yes everything must be repainted. I've painted hundreds of objects before with no problem. For example take a look at [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). You could even use a combination of the two approaches. Paint the fixed objects to a BufferedImage and then paint the moving image on top of the BufferedImage.

Comment: Well I made a change. I create an Object Shape, that extends JPanel, and made PigeonShape and FoodShape extend Shape. Shape has a `static protected Hashtable` where all my shapes are stored. In Shape's `paintComponent`, I repaint every object that are stored in the Hashtable. In PigeonShape and FoodShape `paintComponent`, I call `super.paintComponent`. But it doesn't work... I still have the problem.

Comment: @Nicaps, `I still have the problem.` - well you need to debug your code. I gave you a working example to prove that the concept works. The painting code is simply a loop, I can't guess what you are doing wrong. `Shape has a static protected Hashtable` - why would you use a Hashtable. The working example uses an ArrayList. Why change the basic design when you don't know what you area doing? `

Comment: I create an Object Shape, that extends JPanel,` why? Does the working example create multiple panel objects??? No. There is one painting panel that contains an ArrayList of Shapes to be painted. Check out [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more examples of how to use the existing Shape API to create Rectangles, Ellipsis, Triangles. All you need to do is add each different Shape to the ArrayList and then paint it. Some pseudo code is given in the link to do this.